# Clearing all private user data from Chrome from the command line

Tags: google-chrome

After a cross-country move, I no longer physical access to a certain computer running Ubuntu 12.04, but I do have `ssh` access. I never plan on using Chrome on that computer again, and I would like to clear my cookies, history, cache, and all other private data on that computer from the command line.

I was surprised that I couldn't find any google hits on this topic. Here's one that is close, but it only works for Windows and/or OSX.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61121/clear-out-chrome-history-from-command-line

That site also includes the following warning:

> Google Chrome settings and storage represent user-selected preferences
>   and information and MUST not be extracted, overwritten or modified
>   except through Google Chrome defined APIs.

Is that something to worry about in this case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the default Chrome configuration, run

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/Default
```

and

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome
```

As to the warning from Google, since you aren't going to use it again, and the locations are specific to your HOME location on that machine, don't worry, be happy.

Comment: thanks. to clarify for other readers: `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/` and `rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome`

Comment: This remove the profile completely, extensions included. Would be great to just clear browsing data (browsing and download history, cookies, cache...). Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/a/920604/500826)?

Comment: That's what the OP wanted, complete removal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  After recent update, Chrome crashed when trying to print anything.  I tried the methods of clearing local Chrome and even local Google data, to no avail.  Also used the Settings -> Advanced page in Chrome to reset settings to default, which didn't work either.  I was only able to get printing working in Chrome again by setting up Google Cloud Printing with my local printer.  I followed the directions [here] (https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197) and printing from Chrome finally worked.